# How to config only comment line in xcode?

Tags: xcode

I wish this comment line to be more large and more colorful
[image: code]

But can't find preference setting
how can  I change this font in xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only change the font of **all** comments

- Select Menu **Xcode > Settings** (⌘,)
- Select **Themes** in the toolbar.
- Select a theme or create a new one by duplicating an existing
- Change the font of **Comments**